# Trying to count specific char in 2D array, but entire array is counted instead

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, char, cout

I am trying to count how many times a specific character appears in a 2D array. The problem is that it is counting all characters in the array instead. I'm not sure why.

```
            int P = 0;
            int p = 0;
            int R = 0;
            int r = 0;
            int N = 0;
            int n = 0;
            int B = 0;
            int b = 0;
            int Q = 0;
            int q = 0;

             for (int x = 0; x < BOARD_SIZE + 1; x++) // This side is 9
            {

                for (int y = 0; y < BOARD_SIZE; y++) // This side is 8
                {

                    char temp = ' '; // Tried using temp as pass through, but no difference
                    temp = chessBoards[x][y];
                    // cout << temp; // When this is on it prints each element of the array list in order with a number beside it

                    if (temp = 'P') // This is just one character I am trying to count
                    {
                        ++P; // It increments for every character so it's not checked properly
                    }

                }

            }

             cout << P << endl << endl; // This is what I am using to test output
```

Comment: You *do* know the difference between comparison for equality and assignment? Maybe you need to turn on more warnings for the compiler, because it would detect the problem and warn you about it.

Comment: lol! I can't believe I missed that! It's been a long night. That's all I had to fix. I guess this was just one of those things where I spent too long looking for the wrong issues and overlooked the simple stuff. I'm using Visual Studio Pro for this, which has been bugging lately and requiring restarts. Sometimes, for example, it gives errors where there are no problems requiring a restart. Been making things more difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a typo..

```
if (temp = 'P')
```

You are using assignment operator instead of comparison.

Comment: yeah, thanks. lol. That fixed it. I still can't believe I overlooked something so simple. Well, hopefully this question can still be useful to someone else since it's both an example of counting all characters and counting one character.

Answer (score 1):

Change `if (temp = 'P')` to `if (temp == 'P')`

Answer (score 1):

To test for equality use == and not = (which stands for assignment).
The line "if (temp = 'P')" means that you are assigning 'P' to temp and then testing if temp is different from 0 (the null character), which of course it is ('P' is different from 0!).
The correct way to write the test is:

```
if (temp == 'P')
```

Also, why is the limit in the first for loop different from that in the second for loop? Are you sure about this?

Finally, why do you use x and y to name variables of integer type, wouldn't it be better if you used i and j instead?

Comment: The reason is for different values is because I am storing the new line between boards and using that as a measure for checking how many boards to calculate, but it is still an 8x8 board so I am only going 8 spaces wide.

I have already set it up to check for and remove white spaces between board positions so there's no problem there, and yeah, after the typo was corrected everything works.